# Get today midnight as milliseconds for given timezone java

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, date

I need to get the today midnight time as milliseconds. For example, today's date is 2020-03-20 and I convert this today midnight as milliseconds using the below code. If it works fine in my local environment, but the problem is when I deploy this code to the server, the server has UTC time zone, So even I pass the timezone, the milliseconds returned is wrong. After debugging I found out that this is happening due to parsing the Date, the date uses the default timeZone. I tried to set the timeZone in the Date, but the millisecond value returning is wrong even the date is 2020/03/20 00:00:00. For you to understand more below are some cases.

**In the local Environment: Time Zone pass to method = "Asia/Colombo"**

Date in milliseconds = 1584642600000

Converted date = Fri Mar 20 2020 00:00:00

**In the Server Environment: Time Zone pass to method = "Asia/Colombo"**

Date in milliseconds = 1584662400000

Converted date = Fri Mar 20 2020 05:30:00

Note that here Time Zone is the value I pass to my method parameter. I'm using java 8.

```java
    private static final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy/MM/dd 00:00:00";

    private long getTMT(String timeZone) {
        try {
            ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of(timeZone);
            ZonedDateTime currentZone = ZonedDateTime.now(zoneId);
            ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime =
                    currentZone.withZoneSameInstant(zoneId);
            DateTimeFormatter format =
                    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_FORMAT);
            String formattedDateTime = zonedDateTime.format(format);
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
            Date date = sdf.parse(formattedDateTime);
            return date.getTime();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Hope I explained my question clearly, please let me know your answers/comments on this.

Thank you.

Comment: There's now never a point in time where you need to go through legacy classes. **Especially** if you're going to format and parse intermediately.

Comment: Could you please explain more, does that solve the above problem ?

Comment: Did you try `zonedDateTime.toInstant().toEpochMilli()`? Alternatively `zonedDateTime.toEpochSecond() * 1000`.

Comment: @Thomas, `* 1000` only works because time is fixed.

Comment: Since you can use java.time ( `ZonedDateTime`, etc.), also involving the old and outdated `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date` is completely unnecessary, a detour that just complicates things. Stick to java.time alone.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov yes, it only works because the OP specifically asked for time being 00:00:00,000. In any case it should be obvious that `toEpochSecond()` will return time in second precision only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formatting to string and then parsing from it is a horrible solution, especially since you also have to also construct all these parsers every time, and your format effectively has hacks in it.

There are simpler ways to both construct a midnight ZDT:

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = LocalDate.now(zoneId).atTime(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT).atZone(zoneID);
```

And then extracting the epoch-millis value from it:

```
long epoch = zdt.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
```

Alternatively, since you know that milliseconds and nanoseconds are always `0` at midnight, this is marginally faster:

```
long epoch = zdt.toEpochSecond() * 1000;
```

The second approach wouldn't work if your time is arbitrary, as it will always ignore `milli-of-second` value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, your code removed my redundant code, but I'am not getting the MIDNIGHT time in milliseconds. I got 1584637200000 which is Thu Mar 19 2020 17:00:00 in UTC, Seems like this again changed from timezone to timezone

Comment: @RajithK, You said "today midnight time" and not said anything about UTC. If you need UTC, you will have to use `ZoneOffset.UTC` as input.

Comment: sorry for the confusion the above value i got from https://currentmillis.com/ by converting the milliseconds. I showed you the UTC time, anyway local time did not set to midnight, but UTC time was set to midnight when i use ZoneOffset.UTC

Comment: I am marking this as the answer, since I can use the UTC time for my requirement, Thank you @M. Prokhorov for your answer.

Comment: @RajithK, unless your local time is UTC, then it's impossible for both UTC and local times be set to midnight. I don't even know why that's a discussion.

Comment: yes @M. Prokhorov you are correct, I messed up at that point, your answer is valid. Thank you again for helping.